# Partial state changes for Vaadin's AbstractJavascriptComponent

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm implementing a JavaScript-based Vaadin component that will need to show and update a relatively large data set.  I'm doing this by extending  `AbstractJavaScriptComponent`.

I'm trying to keep the JS side as "dumb" as possible, delegating user interactions to the server using RPC, and which updates the shared state.  Then the JS connector wrapper's `onStateChange` function is called with the new state, which causes the DOM to be updated accordingly.

I have 2 problems:

1. I don't want to transfer the whole data set each time a small part gets updated.
2. I don't want to entirely rebuild the UI each time either.

I can solve the second problem by keeping the previous state and comparing parts of it to find out what changed and only make the necessary DOM changes.
But that still leaves the first problem.

Do I have to stop using Vaadin's shared state mechanism and instead only use RPC for communicating the changes to the state?

**Update**:
I've been doing some testing, and it certainly appears that Vaadin's shared state mechanism is horrible in terms of efficiency:

Whenever the component calls `getState()` in order to update some property in the state object (or even without updating anything), the *whole* state object is transferred.  The only way to avoid this, as far as I can see, is to not use the shared state mechanism and instead use RPC calls to communicate specific state changes to client.

There are some issues with the RPC approach that will need to be resolved, for example: if you change a value multiple times within a single request/response cycle, you don't want to make the RPC call multiple times.  Instead, you want only the last value to be sent just like the shared state mechanism only sends the final state in the response.  You can keep dirty flags for each part of the state that you want to send separately (or just keep a copy of the previous state and compare), but then you need to somehow trigger the RPC call at the end of the request handling.  How can this be done?

Any ideas on this are welcome!

**Update 2**:

Vaadin 8 fixes the root issue: it sends only the changed state properties.  Also, it doesn't call `onStateChange()` on the JS connector anymore when only doing an RPC call (and not changing any state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP is correct in stating that shared state synchronisation is inefficient for `AbstractJavaScriptComponent`-based components. The entire state object is serialised and made available to the Javascript connector's `onStateChange` method whenever the connector is marked as dirty. Other non-javascript components handle state updates more intelligently by only sending changes. The exact place in the code where this happens is line 97 in `com.vaadin.server.LegacyCommunicationManager.java`

```
boolean supportsDiffState = !JavaScriptConnectorState.class
            .isAssignableFrom(stateType);
```

I'm not sure why state update is handled differently for `AbstractJavaScriptComponent`-based components. Maybe it's to simplify the javascript connector and remove the need to assemble a complete state object from deltas. It would be great if this could be addressed in a future version.

As you suggest, you could dispense with `JavaScriptComponentState` completely and rely on server->client RPC for updates. Keep dirty flags in you server-side component or compare old state and new state by any mechanism you want.

To coalesce the changes and send only one RPC call for each change, you could override `beforeClientResponse(boolean initial)` in your server-side component. This is called just before sending a response to the client and is your chance to add a set of RPC calls to update the client-side component.

Alternatively, you could override `encodeState` where you have free-reign to send exactly whatever JSON you like to the client. You could choose to add a list of changes to the base JSON object returned by `super.encodeSate`. Your javascript connector could interpret as appropriate in its `onStateChange` method.

Edited to add: calling `getState()` in your server-side component will mark the connector as dirty. If you want to get state without marking it as dirty then use `getState(false)` instead.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for.  When "cheating" by not sending the full state when overriding encodeState, are there any caveats regarding detach and attach?  For example should the full state be sent after being detached and reattached?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to unaccept the answer for now.  The reason is that it is not possible to prevent the full state being transferred (and the `onStateChange()` JS function being called) since `AbstractComponent#beforeClientResponse(boolean initial)` calls `getState()` repeatedly, marking the connector as dirty.  Of course we can override, but I'm sure that code exists for a reason.  IMO this is a Vaadin bug.

Comment: I filed [this ticket](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/19828) on their issue tracker.  I'll have to find some way to work around it.

Comment: Trying to work around the issue by overriding `getState()` to call `super.getState(false)` and calling `markAsDirty()` explicitly only when needed, revealed another issue: any JS function call (through `callFunction(...)`) will call `markAsDirty()` and cause the JS connector's `onStateChange()` to be called. Filed [yet another ticket](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/19837)

Comment: BTW Vaadin 8 fixes all these issues.  See https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/20335 which fixes also https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/19837 and https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/19828

Answer (score 0):

Following our discussion about this, I've created a drop-in replacement for AbstractJavaScriptComponent that transmits state deltas and includes some extra enhancements. It's in the very early stages but should be useful.

https://github.com/emuanalytics/vaadin-enhancedjavascript

The solution is deceptively simple: basically re-enabling state difference calculation by bypassing this line of code in `com.vaadin.server.LegacyCommunicationManager.java`:

```
boolean supportsDiffState = !JavaScriptConnectorState.class
        .isAssignableFrom(stateType);
```

The implementation of the solution is complicated by the fact that the Vaadin classes are not easily extended so I've had to copy and re-implement 6 classes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look when I have time.  I've noticed before as well that Vaadin classes are difficult to extend because of `private`/`final` stuff.  I still think the unnecessary calls to the JS connector wrapper's `onStateChange()` function need to be fixed even when the diff algorithm is enabled.  Right now I've worked around that part of the problem by adding a `version` property to the state and incrementing that only when actually changing some state properties, then comparing that with the previous value in the connector wrapper.

Comment: Btw would it be preferable to use this addon instead of not using shared state at all and simply explicitly calling JS methods (using `callFunction`) to communicate certain state changes (using the coalescing in `beforeClientResponse` as you described in the other answer)?  That way the client also doesn't have to figure out what changed by inspecting the deltas.

Comment: With this component, onStateChange() is NOT invoked when using callFunction() to do server->client RPC. You are free to use shared state or RPC without any bloated payloads. In this respect, using this component is just the same as using a 'native' vaadin/GWT-based component. Whether to use shared state or RPC (or a mixture of both) is up to you and will depend on what sort of API is exposed by the Javascript component that you are wrapping. For example, if the API is a flat, procedural based API then RPC is probably more suitable. I'm using it to wrap MapboxGL.js and am using a mix.

Comment: One good use of shared state is for passing the initial parameters and options required to initialise your Javascript component. These can be set in shared state in you Java component constructor and are immediately available on the Javascript side for creating the Javascript component.

Comment: Indeed.  I was thinking of working around the issue regarding state, and still have a way to initialize the component with an initial state, by just calling an RPC function (called 'setState' or similar) immediately when the server side component is constructed.  I think it would be sent in the same initial response as the shared state.

Comment: There is now a new Vaadin ticket about this: https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/20335 - it sounds like it may be a little more complicated than what you've done (although I'm not sure why) but they'll try to get it in for Vaadin 8 (see https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/8350615/14119965)

Answer (score -1):

Vaadin's shared state works exactly like you want out of the box: when a component is added to the DOM first time, the whole shared state is transferred from server to client, so that it's possible to display the component. After that, only changes are transferred. For example, one changes the caption of a visible component by calling `component.setCaption("new caption")`, Vaadin only transfers that new caption text to client and "merges" that to the client-side shared state instance of the component.

Comment: How does that work when nested properties are changed?  For example if my state object has a list of persons, and one of the persons addresses have changed?  What is transferred: the whole list, a single person, or a single address?

Comment: Sorry but have to downvote.  I tested this: the component calls `getState()` in order to update any value (also in `setCaption()`), which causes the connector to be marked as dirty, and then I see the whole state being transferred even if only a single value has changed.   In fact, even if nothing has changed (only `getState()` called).

Comment: Herman is correct in stating that change-detection is not implemented for `AbstractJavaScriptComponent`-based components. See my answer for detail.